# Loop within a column with non numerical data

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, statistics

I have a data frame with three columns. The first column involves the questions, the second column involves the answer types (passive, active, neither) and the third column involves the ID (e.g., 1,2,3...) of the participant. For each participant, there are 18 questions. I want to create a loop where for each participant I can count the number of active, passive, and neither responses. I tried to do with aggregate and group by function but it did not work. As my data is not numerical I could not find the appropriate function. How can I solve this? My data frame looks like this:

```
questions  resp_type  participant
question1  active     1
question2  passive    1
.
.
.
question18 neither    1
question1  passive    2
question2  active     2
question3  active     2
. 
.
.
```

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, participant, resp_type)`

Comment: Or `aggregate(questions ~ participant + resp_type, data = df, length)`